# I accidentally serialized an object containing a non-serializable field; now I need to get it back

Tags: java, serialization, deserialization

I am making a game. The game designer creates a `Game` object, then saves it to the hard drive; to play the game, the user loads the `Game` object from the hard drive. The `Game` object is `Serializable`. The `Game` object contains thousands of other objects (`Map`, `Person`, `Tile`s, etc.), all of which are also `Serializable`.

Unfortunately, I accidentally added a new feature to my game: a class called `Large`. I forgot to implement the `Serializable` interface on `Large`. Then I added a `Large` object to an existing `Game` file that I had spent a considerable amount of time working on. When I saved my `Game` file, a `NotSerializableException` exception occurred.

I am trying to recover from this error and retrieve my `Game` file from the hard drive in a usable form, so that I can continue to design my game without having to create it all over again. Unfortunately, when I try to load the file, I get a `NotSerializableException`. I have tried the following strategies, without success:

- implementing `Serializable` on my `Large` class
- making the '`large`' variable `transient`

Do you have any other solutions?

Comment: Please include relevant portions of your Game class to the question. Also, what do you mean by `Then I added a Large object to an existing Game file that I had spent a considerable amount of time working on.`? You modified a physical file? Or its in-memory representation?

Comment: @Perception I loaded my game object from the hard drive, altered it by adding a Large object, then saved (or attempted to save) it to disk.

Comment: @VanCity In this case I think it is still the old version. If the Exception occurred it means it didn't save it.

Comment: @VanCity - did you maintain the same `serialVersionUID` for the class? Still waiting on you to include relevant portions of your `Game` class to the question. You might also want to include the error stacktrace you get when trying to save the updated game file.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you sure the game was actually saved? If the exception occurred when you were saving the file I don't think it managed to serialize the object.

The problem you are facing in fact is the major flaw of using serialized objects for these kinds of things. The moment you do changes to the class such as one of the following the old serialized objects become incompatible.

1. Remove a field
2. Change the object's superclass
3. Change a non-static field to static (or vice versa)
4. Change a type of a field.

You should use your own data format (while you're still in time). You can choose a data format of your choice, or even use XML or JSON (the latter is becoming more popular these days since its more lightweight) and there are APIs available to save objects quickly and easily.

Comment: "The moment you do one change (like adding a new variable or changing something) the old serialized objects become invalid." This statement is completely incorrect. See the [Versioning of Serialized Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/serialization/spec/version.html) chapter of the Object Serialization Specification.

Comment: It is not completely incorrect. Yes, in certain cases you can do a backward compatible change, but from a practical point of view it makes it very difficult for the object to be refactored and improved. I will re-edit the answer, but fundamentally serialized object are very limited for long-term object persistence.

Comment: Answer edited for a more precise description, however the main message here is do not use serialized objects in this kind of circumstance

Comment: @EJP Thank you for the reference to the Object Serialization Specification. I will read this document.

Comment: It was completely incorrect to state that adding a variable causes the old serialised object to become invalid, and it is now completely incorrect to say that removing a field does so.

Comment: @EJP No you are incorrect. Check the same link you suggested, Section 5.6.1 Incompatible Changes.

Comment: @jbx No, I am not incorrect. It says: "Deleting fields - If a field is deleted in a class, the stream written will not contain its value. When the stream is read by an earlier class, the value of the field will be set to the default value because no value is available in the stream. However, this default value may adversely impair the ability of the earlier version to fulfill its contract." That *may* be a semantic problem for the application. It is *not* an incompatibility with a previously serialised stream.